# WPF context menu auto scroll

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, scrollviewer

I have a context menu in WPF with, say, 40 menu items. I limited the height of the context menu to, say "130" so that only five item appear at a time. It perfectly automatically assigned scrollviewer which a user can use to scroll the items. In the mean time, I need to capture ScrollChanged event so that I could remember the last scroll position and assign it later. ScrollViewer in

does not have anything I could use for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can check the VerticalOffset. The VerticalOffset property is between 0 and ScrollableHeight. Read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticaloffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
private void OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)sender;
   if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == 0)
          MessageBox.Show("This is the start.");
   else if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight)
          MessageBox.Show("This is the end"); 
}
```

Similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793717/how-to-find-that-scrollviewer-is-scrolled-to-the-end-in-wpf).