# WPF - Set image visibility when ScrollViewer is scrolled

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `ScrollViewer` on a WPF user control and what I'd like to achieve is to show a shadow image at the top and bottom of the `ScrollViewer`, but hide the top shadow when the scrollbar is at the top, and hide the bottom shadow when the scrollbar is at the bottom.

In other words, I need to bind the `Visibility` property of the image to the offset of the `ScrollViewer` somehow. The following code is clearly not right but should illustrate what I'm trying to do.

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="Shadow.png" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Scroller" Property="VerticalOffset" Value="GREATER THAN ZERO OR LESS THAN MAX">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Resources>
    </Image>
    <ScrollViewer Height="200" x:Name="Scroller">
        <ContentControl />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I think this may (at least partially) answer your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793717/how-to-find-that-scrollviewer-is-scrolled-to-the-end-in-wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

First, you'll need an IMultiValueConverter:

```
public class ScrollOffsetToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Values cannot be null.");
        if (values.Count() != 2)
            throw new ArgumentException("Incorrect number of bindings (" + values.Count() + ")");
        if (parameter == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null.");

        var top = parameter.ToString().ToUpper() == "TOP";

        var offset = Double.Parse(values[0].ToString());
        var maxHeight = Double.Parse(values[1].ToString());

        return (top && offset == 0) || (!top && offset == maxHeight) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then, you can use this converter to apply a Setter for the Visibility property of your image.

```
<Image.Style Source="Shadow.png" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Image.Visibility">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ScrollOffsetToVisibilityConverter}" ConverterParameter="Top">
                    <Binding ElementName="Scroller" Path="VerticalOffset"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="Scroller" Path="ScrollableHeight"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Image.Style>
```

Just pass in "top" or "bottom" (or more accurately, not "top") for the ConverterParameter to return "Visible" if the scroll bar is at the top or bottom.

Comment: This code really helped me out - however I had to swap Visible and Collapsed in the converter code as the behavior was the opposite of what I wanted in combination with my Grid element I manipulated with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ScrollBar` instead of `ScrollViewer` because `ScrollViewer` can't tell when it reaches the end of its content. (or at least I haven't seen a reliable method for doing so). On the other hand `ScrollBar` is more suitable for these kinds of operations.

I used a ListBox with several items to test this behavior. you can change it to whatever you need.

Xaml :

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ScrollBar.Scroll="ListBox_Scroll">
        <!-- add many items here -->
        <TextBlock Text="something"/>
    </ListBox>

    <Image Source="Shadow.png" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ScrollerState}" 
                            Value="{x:Static enum:ScrollState.AtTheTop}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
    <Image Source="Shadow.png" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ScrollerState}" 
                          Value="{x:Static enum:ScrollState.AtTheBottom}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

As you can see I changed the trigger to `DataTrigger` and used a bindable property in DataContext (named `ScrollerState` with type of `ScrollState` which is a simple enum) to bind to.

enum:

```
public enum ScrollState
{
    AtTheTop, AtTheBottom, InBetween
}
```

Now in Code behind we implement the Scroll event from where we change the value of `ScrollerState`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new VM();
}

private void ListBox_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollBar sb = e.OriginalSource as ScrollBar;

    if (sb.Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
        return;

    if (sb.Value == 0)
        (DataContext as VM).ScrollerState = ScrollState.AtTheTop;
    else if (sb.Value == sb.Maximum)
        (DataContext as VM).ScrollerState = ScrollState.AtTheBottom;
    else
        (DataContext as VM).ScrollerState = ScrollState.InBetween;
}
```

VM (an instance of this is set as DataContext of the window):

```
public class VM : DependencyObject
{
    public ScrollState ScrollerState
    {
        get { return (ScrollState)GetValue(ScrollerStateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScrollerStateProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollerStateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ScrollerState", typeof(ScrollState), typeof(VM), 
        new PropertyMetadata(ScrollState.AtTheTop));
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated and I'm sure this would have worked - I went with the alternative suggestion since it didn't require any code behind.